# Vertex Names as Labels in GraphPlots

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I'm trying to use GraphPlot to draw a Graph which is constructed from an adjacency matrix and am having trouble with the labels in the plot. I am doing (data is a silly example) the following:

```
data = Import["~/test.mtx", "MatrixMarket"]
verts = {"Aa", "Ba", "Ca", "Da", "Ea"}

g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[verts, data, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Which correctly results in a labelled Adjacency Graph:

[image: Graph Representation]

However, when I try and render the graph using a GraphPlot (or similar function...) I always get numbered labels instead. Eg:

```
GraphPlot[g, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .1], 
     Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

renders as:

[image: GraphPlot rendering of g]

My question is how can I get GraphPlot (and similar) to use the vertex names like Graph itself does? Alternatively, is there a better way of providing vertex names when using an Adjacency Matrix? (My real dataset has many thousands of vertices and edges).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2:** There is a *hidden* option `"VertexNames"` for labeling vertices in `GraphPlot` (also works with `LayeredGraphPlot` and `TreePlot`):

```
verts = {"Aa", "Ba", "Ca", "Da", "Ea", "Fa"};

g1 = CompleteGraph[6, 
   VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[verts[[v]], Center]}, 
   VertexSize -> Medium, ImageSize -> 400];

g2 = GraphPlot[g1, ImageSize -> 400, VertexLabeling -> True, "VertexNames" -> verts];

Row[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]

***Note:*** In version 12.0+, you need to use `` GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy ``,`` GraphComputation`LayeredGraphPlotLegacy `` and `` GraphComputation`TreePlotLegacy `` for `GraphPlot`, `LayeredGraphPlot` and `TreePlot`, respectively.

**Original answer:**

You can modify your `VertexRenderingFunction` using `Text[verts[[#2]], #1]` instead of `Text[#2, #1]`:

```
verts = {"Aa", "Ba", "Ca", "Da", "Ea", "Fa"};

g1 = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; (i != j) -> 1}, {6, 6}, \[Infinity]], 
   VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[6] -> verts], ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 400];
g2 = GraphPlot[g1, ImageSize -> 400,  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black],
   Disk[#, .1], Black, Text[verts[[#2]], #1]} &)];
Row[{g1, g2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

or, using `Text[#2 /. PropertyValue[g1, VertexLabels], #1]`

```
g3 = GraphPlot[g1, ImageSize -> 400, VertexRenderingFunction ->
   ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .1], Black, 
      Text[#2 /. PropertyValue[g1, VertexLabels], #1]} &)]
```

[image]

**Update:** Unless you have special reasons to use `GraphPlot`, you can achieve the same results using `Graph`:

```
wam = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; (i != j) -> 1}, {6, 6}, \[Infinity]];
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[Labeled[#, Style[#, 24, "Panel", Background -> None], Center] & /@ verts, 
      wam, VertexSize -> Large]
```

or

```
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[wam, VertexSize -> Large,
 VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[6] -> 
   (Placed[Style[#, 24, "Panel", Background -> None], Center] & /@ verts)]]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: It feels to me as though GraphPlot (and similar) should just pick up the vertex names provided to the Graph and is therefore "buggy", but these are useful ways round it. Thanks.

Comment: @barns, thank you for the Accept.