# How to generate the EdgeList from an matrix that produces a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How do I find the EdgeList of the matrix that Mathematica generates below?

[image]

Comment: Providing all definition of variables what you have used.

Comment: Next time, please provide code in easily copyable format, instead of making people manually retype the code you used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aa = {{"", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"}, {"A", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
      {"B", 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"C", 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
      {"D", 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {"E", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
      {"F", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"G", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}};

MatrixForm[aa]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
gp = GraphPlot[aa, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you have access only to the graphics output (not to the matrix `aa`) you can post-process the graphics output:

```
edgelist = Cases[gp[[1]], Arrow[x_] :> (Rule @@ x), {0, Infinity}];

GraphPlot[edgelist, DirectedEdges -> True, MultiedgeStyle -> None, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you have access to the matrix `aa`, then you can use

```
edgelist2 = Rest[Rule @@@ SparseArray[aa]["NonzeroPositions"]]
```

to get the same result directly without needing to process the graphics output:

```
edgelist == edgelist2
```

> True

**Note:** I have taken the adjacency matrix as is, so the number of vertices is 8. However, the matrix `aa` is likely to be the adjacency matrix for a graph with 7 vertices with the first row and column giving the vertex labels. If that's the case, the correct graph would be

```
gp2 = GraphPlot[aa[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]], DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Update:` Changing vertex labels to `"A", "B",...`:

```
labels = Rest@First@aa;
edges = Rule @@@ (SparseArray[aa[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]]["NonzeroPositions"]);
newedges = edges /. Thread[Range[7] -> labels];
GraphPlot[newedges, DirectedEdges -> True, MultiedgeStyle -> None, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See also [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67510/125) on *Vertex Names as Labels in GraphPlots*.

Comment: wonderful!! Many thanks kglr!!

Comment: How can I put the vertex labels A, B, C on the node instead of the number?

Comment: @PRG, for `gp` or `gp2`?

Comment: i would like to add labels A, B, C etc to the nodes instead ... on gp2

Comment: @PRG, please see the update.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help; many many thanks kglr!!

Comment: @PRG, glad to be of use. Welcome to the mma.se. Please remember to upvote questions and answers that you find useful; and to accept the answer that you find most useful among the posted answers to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use `AdjacencyGraph`/`EdgeList`. Here is the adjacency graph associated with `aa`:

```
aa = {{"", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"}, {"A", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
      {"B", 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"C", 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
      {"D", 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {"E", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
      {"F", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"G", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}};

AdjacencyGraph[
    aa[[1, 2;;]],
    aa[[2;;,2;;]],
    VertexLabels->Automatic
]
```

[image]

And, here is the associated edge list:

```
EdgeList @ AdjacencyGraph[aa[[1, 2;;]], aa[[2;;, 2;;]]] //InputForm
```

> {DirectedEdge["A", "B"], DirectedEdge["A", "C"], 
>    DirectedEdge["A", "D"], DirectedEdge["B", "A"], 
>    DirectedEdge["B", "C"], DirectedEdge["B", "D"], 
>    DirectedEdge["C", "A"], DirectedEdge["C", "B"], 
>    DirectedEdge["C", "E"], DirectedEdge["C", "F"], 
>    DirectedEdge["C", "G"], DirectedEdge["D", "A"], 
>    DirectedEdge["D", "B"], DirectedEdge["D", "C"], 
>    DirectedEdge["D", "G"], DirectedEdge["E", "B"], 
>    DirectedEdge["E", "C"], DirectedEdge["E", "D"], 
>    DirectedEdge["F", "B"], DirectedEdge["F", "C"], 
>    DirectedEdge["F", "D"], DirectedEdge["G", "A"], 
>    DirectedEdge["G", "B"], DirectedEdge["G", "C"], 
>    DirectedEdge["G", "D"], DirectedEdge["G", "F"]}

Comment: wonderful Carl; thank you for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

The edge list is simply the position of ones in the matrix:

```
aa = {{"", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"}, {"A", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
      {"B", 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"C", 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
      {"D", 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {"E", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
      {"F", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"G", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}};

edges = Rule @@@ Position[aa[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]], 1]
```

> ```
> {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 
>  3 -> 7, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 4 -> 7, 5 -> 2, 5 -> 3, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 2, 6 -> 3, 
>  6 -> 4, 7 -> 1, 7 -> 2, 7 -> 3, 7 -> 4, 7 -> 6}
> ```

```
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, aa[[1, 2 ;;]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Mr. Wizard: I've learned a lot from these discussions; many thanks for your help and for sharing your insights and skills ... prg